# How can I make sure that sent emails do not land in Spam?

Tags: php

I am using the following code nowadays, however, email lands to spambox, pls help me to fix this error

```
<?php    
$to = "youremail@gmail.com";
$subject = "mail with attachment";    
$att = file_get_contents( 'name.pdf' );
$att = base64_encode( $att );
$att = chunk_split( $att );    
$BOUNDARY="anystring";    
$headers =<<<END
From: Your Name <abc@gmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=$BOUNDARY
END;

$body =<<<END
--$BOUNDARY
Content-Type: text/plain    
See attached file!    
--$BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="your-file.pdf"    
$att
--$BOUNDARY--
END;    
mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );

?>
```

please help me to fix this error

Thank You

Comment: You have to use `SMTP` for this purpose. check for  `PHPMAILER`

Comment: can you please give any best link for SMTP

Comment: PHPMAILER i already said

Answer (score 1):

Try header with MIME version

```
$headers.= "MIME-version: 1.0\n";
$headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset= iso-8859-1\n";
```

Comment: can you make sure there are no empty spaces in your message body

Answer (score 1):

Getting into spam box is relative to :

- Subject
- Sender Name
- Sender Email

It works like reputations, and if you use something "abc@gmail.com" for your testing purpose you have great chance to get into spambox, no matter what code you are using !

At least try to test with plausible Emails, like your own personal one

Comment: i try from my personal email also but no use, it also going to spam only

Comment: Can you try with same configuration, but different body  ? like a simple plain text

Comment: can you please send any email script with pdf attachment, using SMTP

Answer (score 0):

Use https://www.mail-tester.com/ to test your e-mails spam score. This website will also give you tips how to improve your mail. When you have any question about some problems mail-tester returns, posts them here and I will help you with solving them.